# Return of two components in JAVA

Tags: java, return

i have written the following method in JAVA:

```
protected List<Symbol> fields = new ArrayList<OCLFieldSymbol>();   (**)


public List<Symbol> getArgs(TypeArt kind) {

return (kind, fields);

}
```

I use Eclipse and it underlines "fields" in the return section with red. When I put the mouse to the red-underlined place, Exclipse makes the following suggestions:

```
  Create field `fields` in type `TypeArt`
  Create constant fields in type `TypeArt`
```

But I do not want to create such a field. It should return the "fields" from the first line (see (**)).
What can I do ? I am new in JAVA and learning it. So I hope someone can help me.

best regards

Comment: The method is not returning `List<Symbol>`

Comment: Can you please explore bit more ? Your question look hard to understand also used lots of class and interface  also `return (kind, fields)` ?

Comment: You cannot return multiple objects in Java like you would do in few languages like python. You instead have to create a list object. Add `kind` and `fields` to the list. And then return it.

Comment: So, I should write List<Object> instead of List<Symbol>, add the two and then return them ?

Comment: Why do you want to return kind ?

Comment: When you created the method you used `List<Symbol>` this is telling the return statement that it has to be a list of Symbols. You either need to make a List of symbols in the method `getArgs` or you need to change that type to something else.

Comment: @BoutayaBilal: kind is like the type of the field, e.g. int x. I want that it should give me all fields with that type int, for example.

Comment: getArgs(TypeArt kind) means you have the 'kind', you don't need to get it back after calling the method.

Comment: @BoutayaBilal: What I meant was: the Symbol objects have all a certain kind. I want to put kind as argument to select all symbol objects with that certain kind.

Comment: You need just to return Symbol objects (List<Symbol>) and not the kind.

Comment: ok, but why I dont need some lines of code in which I search the list for the  symbolobject with that kind? Or is that done automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Java methods are limited to at most one return value, in this case a `List<Symbol>`. If you really need to have multiple values returned--and you usually don't--you will need to make a class to contain them.

In this case, you're already passing `kind` in as a parameter, so it doesn't make sense to try to return it; just `return fields`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
public List<Symbol> getArgs(TypeArt kind) {
    List<Symbol> temp= new ArrayList<Symbol>();
    for (Symbol field:fields){
        //determine if field is the kind you want it to be
        //if it is add it to temp using temp.add(field)
    }
    return temp;

}
```

If you want to return all the elements from `fields` that are of type `kind` you first need to create a new list using `new List<Symbol>`. Once the list is set up you then need to go though the list and determine which ones are the type you want. If they match the type you want you add them to your new list. when you are done looping you return the new list.  In your method you told it that it will be returning a `List<Symbol>` that means that the return statement needs to be a list of symbols. `(kind, fields)` is not a `List` object.

Comment: thanks, I think this is exactly what I need. The line with for(Symbol field:fields)...is that typical for List ? Because in the chapter "Loops" in my JAVA Book, I do not see it.

Comment: its a different way of looping. you could use `for (int i=0; i<fields.size(); i++)` but then you would have to call `fields.get(i)` to get each item in the list. the other way `for(Symbol field:fields)` it is saying for each symbol named field in the list of fields...... that way you can just call `field` instead of using `get()` either way will work though.

Comment: this might help you understand the loop a little better: [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm)

Comment: @user3097712 If your Java book does not cover for-each loops, which have been available for a decade, it's time to get a new book.